# Is there an algorithm for establishing isomorphism between matrix Lie algebras?

Tags: matrices, algorithms, lie-algebras

Let $\left\{A_i\right\}_{i=1}^{n}$ and $\left\{B_i\right\}_{i=1}^{n}$ be sets of complex-valued matrices of order $N$ and $M$ respectively. Each set is mutually orthogonal in that $$\operatorname{tr}\left( A_i^{\dagger}A_j\right) = \delta_{ij}$$ $$\operatorname{tr}\left( B_i^{\dagger}B_j\right) = \delta_{ij}$$

Each set is also the basis for a Lie algebra such that $$\left[A_i,A_j\right] \in \operatorname{span}\left\{A\right\}\;\forall\; i,j$$ $$\left[B_i,B_j\right] \in \operatorname{span}\left\{B\right\}\;\forall\; i,j$$

Given these two sets as inputs, is there a known algorithm for determining whether the two Lie algebras are isomorphic?

(If it's of any consequence, both Lie algebras are known to be semi-simple.)

Comment: It helps a great deal to know that both Lie algebras are semisimple; I think the problem is unsolvable otherwise. Since the classification of semisimple Lie algebras is known you just have to determine which semisimple Lie algebra each Lie algebra is.

Comment: This is not even a well-posed problem, since matrix coefficients are merely complex numbers, which means that you cannot input them in a Turing machine. There are several model of real computability (Real RAM, bit computability....) and you have to decide which one of them you are going to use.

Comment: @MoisheCohen: It would suffice in my case that the structure constant tensors $a_{ij}^{k}$ and $b_{ij}^{k}$ be equivalent (numerically equal $\pm$ some small error) modulo a unitary change of basis. In terms of computability, I'm simply looking for something that can run in a matter of minutes on a modern PC for $n \leq 20$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Thanks for your response. Just so I'm not reinventing the wheel, would you happen to know if any software or code library exists that could perform such a classification? Or is it something I'd have to write from scratch?

Comment: @COTO: In this setting you cannot tell, say, nilpotent, Lia algebras apart from each other. Your only chance to work with, say, integer, structure constants (even this might not be enough). In any case, I do not think there are ready-made algorithms.

Comment: Also, take a look here: https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap64.html, it might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here:

V. P. Gerdt,  W. Lassner, *Isomorphism verification for complex and real Lie algebras by Gröbner basis technique.* In: Modern group analysis: advanced analytical and computational methods in mathematical physics (Acireale, 1992), 245–254, Kluwer Acad. Publ., Dordrecht, 1993.

From the Math Review description of this paper:

> The package ISOLIE/ASYS is introduced. It allows one to decide whether two finite-dimensional complex or real Lie algebras given by structure constants are isomorphic or not and to construct existing isomorphisms. The package uses the technique of Gröbner bases of ideals of algebras of commutative polynomials. ISOLIE/ASYS needs seconds for Lie algebras of dimension 3, minutes for dimensions 4 and 5, hours for dimension 6 and days for dimensions 7 and 8.

This was written back in 1992, so nowdays the program should run much faster. However, you need to know precise structure constants, not their approximation.

Comment: Ah. Many, many thanks! :D